# Unable to sort Array while implementing QuickSort

Tags: c, quicksort

I have implemented quicksort with 2 different  approach taken in partition set

these are the programs

> 1.http://ideone.com/fPtQFT
>
> 2.http://ideone.com/KuXKr4

1.

```
int partition(int *a,int l,int r)
{
    int i=l,pivot=l;
    int j=l+1;
    for(;j<r;j++)
    {
      if(a[j]<a[pivot])
      {
        swap(&a[i+1],&a[j]);
        i++;
      }
    }
    swap(&a[pivot],&a[i]);
    return i;
  }
```

2.

```
 int partition(int *a,int l,int r)

 {
    int pivot=l;
   int j=r-1;
   int i=l+1;
    while(1)
   {
     while(i<=j&&a[i]<=a[pivot])
        i++;
     while(i<=j&&a[j]>=a[pivot])
        j--;
     if(j<i)
        break;
     else
        swap(&a[i],&a[j]);

   }
   swap(&a[pivot],&a[j]);

   return j;

 }
```

I am unable to figure out what's wrong in my code as the sorted output for example the test case
`13 2 43 3 55  21 43 1 5 32`
are wrong `1 2 3 13 21 32 42 5 43 55`

Any help to figure out what's wrong in the logic of partitionset

Comment: Post the code here please, do not link to external sites without including code here. And post only one example.

Comment: The code was big so I thought my error would be in partition_set implementation that's why I pasted that,But thanks to you for pointing out my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quicksort function takes the range in the form m to n where, m is the first element and n is one past the last element. This is done correctly in the main:

```
quicksort(a,0,N);
```

This means the second argument denotes the first element: `0`, and the third argument denotes the one past the last element: `N`.

This is not done correctly in the first recursive call, where the last element is skipped because p-1 denotes the last element, instead of one past the last element:

```
quicksort(a,l,p-1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to sort the array using quick sort [Quick sort](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/)

```
QuickSort(A, P , R)
    {
        if(P < R)
        {
            Q = partition(A, P , R);
            QuickSort(A, P, Q - 1);
            QuickSort(A, Q + 1, R);
        }
    }

    int partition(A, P , R)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            key = A[P];
            i = P;
            j = R;
            while(key > A[i] && key != A[i])
                i++;
        while(key < A[j] && key != A[j])
            j--;
        if(i < j)
        swap(A[i],A[j]); 
    else
        return j;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't help by diagnosing what is wrong with the OP's code, so it really isn't an answer to the question.  You'd have to explain what's different between your code and the code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

this should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

void swap(int *a,int*b)
{
    int temp=*b;
    *b=*a;
    *a=temp;
}

int partition(int *a,int l,int r)
{
    int i=l,pivot=a[r];
    int j=l;
    for(;j<r;j++)
    {
      if(a[j]<pivot)
      {
        swap(&a[i],&a[j]);
        i++;
      }
    }
    swap(&a[i],&a[r]);
    return i;
  }


void quicksort(int *a,int l,int r){
    int p;
    if(l<r)
    {
        p=partition(a,l,r);
        quicksort(a,l,p-1);
        quicksort(a,p+1,r);
    }
}


int main(){
    int a[N] = {13, 2, 43, 3, 55,  21, 43, 1, 5, 32};
    int i;
    quicksort(a,0,N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```